# Reuse WebView Activity within the application

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity, android-webview

I created an activity with only a WebView in that activity and I would like to use that activity in multiple places, where I just need to pass in the URL and PAGETITLE as the parameter, what's the best practice to get it work or should I create a new activity for every webview that I need to load?

Thanks

```
public class WebviewActivity extends BaseAppCompatActivity {
private WebView mWebView;
private String mPageTitle,mUrl;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_webview);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras == null) {
        mPageTitle = "pagetitle";
        mUrl = null;

    } else {
        mPageTitle = extras.getString(Constants.PAGE_TITLE);
        mUrl = extras.getString(Constants.URL);
    }

    if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mPageTitle);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    mWebView.loadUrl(mUrl);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            onBackPressed();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well you can reuse this activity isnt it? Why ask?

Comment: I am learning Android and I just want to confirm the best practice for things like this, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reuse this activity just like any other activity, by sending an `Intent` to start it:

```
// "this" references the context
Intent intent = new Intent(this, WebviewActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(Constants.PAGE_TITLE, "Stack Overflow");
intent.putExtra(Constants.URL, "http://stackoverflow.com/");
startActivity(intent);
```

The system handles its lifecycle (creating, destroying, etc.), so this is the only thing you should do to reuse it.

Comment: Great, the lifecycle part is all I need to know, thanks!